# How use Pkcs11interop Xamarin.Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, pkcs11interop

i want to create a Xamarin.Mac app to read data from eID card. Where i can find an information about **pkcs11interop + Xamarin** or where i can find an examples.

Or, how can i load a iOS library:

```
                    String path = "beid_ff_pkcs11.dll";
                    Pkcs11 pkcs11;

                    try
                    {
                        pkcs11 = new Pkcs11(path, AppType.MultiThreaded);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show($"Pkcs11 pkcs not loaded");
                        return;
                    }
```

Best Reagards
Nikita

Answer (score 0):

[Code samples](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/4.0.0/doc/CODE_SAMPLES.md) are available in the git repository. They are valid for all supported operating systems including Mac OS X.